# gethostbyname() failure - host name lookup failure

Tags: c, sockets, gethostbyname

I need to implement a client server program and I have very weird problem.
In the program I connect to the server and send http request to it.
At the first try after compilation I get: "gethostbyname(): host name lookup failure". But if I try again the problem is gone, even if I don't recompile my program.
I checked the url and it is fine. I think there might be a problem in the connector function.

```
int connector(Input* in)
{

    int fd = socket(PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    if(fd<0)
    {
        destruct(in);
        perror("socket-connect");
        exit(ERROR);
    }


    struct hostent *hp = gethostbyname(in->host);
    if(hp == NULL)
    {
        destruct(in);
        herror("gethosbyname func");
        exit(ERROR);
    }

    struct sockaddr_in srv_addr;
    srv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    srv_addr.sin_port = htons(in->port);
    srv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = ((struct in_addr *)hp->h_addr)->s_addr;


    if(connect(fd,(struct sockaddr*)&srv_addr,sizeof(srv_addr))<0)
    {
        destruct(in);
        perror("connect func - connect");
        exit(ERROR);
    }

    return fd;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the value of `h_errno` variable?

Comment: how do i check it?

Comment: If `gethostbyname` fails, what makes you think the problem is with `connect`?

Comment: i ment to "connnector", sory.

Comment: @k2k, `printf("h_errno: %d\n", h_errno);`

Comment: ok the h_errno is 2. it mean try again.

Comment: The issue may be due to /etc/resolv.conf . Reboot and then a new resolv.conf file will be generated. Then execute your program

Comment: it didn't help...

Comment: If h_errno says "TRY_AGAIN", then you should do that. The DNS server failed the query and asks that you should try again, and there is pretty much nothing you can do about that except verify that all your settings on your machine related to DNS is configured properly. If you have control over the DNS server you are using, verify that it is configured and operating properly too.

Comment: `gethostbyname()` is deprecated anyway, you should be using `getaddrinfo()` instead.